# Karate UI: unable to find the child element using friendly locator and looking for some alternatives

Tags: karate

Looking for an alternative of findElement.findElement like in selenium. I have tried chainable keywords available in like friendly locators but none of them worked. I want to get the text of 'p' and I can achieve it by using XPath however in selenium we could use findElement($parentDiv).findElement($p) will work.

```
<div class="example">
 <span class="new"></span>
 <p>Random Text</p>
</div>
```

Xpath will fail if there are any new changes in the UI however findElement.findElement won't.
Does Karate-UI have a solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 0.9.6.RC3 - you should be able to chain `locate()`

```
* def e = locate('.example')
* match e.locate('p').text == 'Random Text'
```

Else please follow this process so that the scenario is more clear - and help us fix this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. I will try and let you know the result.